# what is role of cfinger in below output of lsof -i

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lsof

I would like to understand the output of `lsof -i`, come with below response

below, it looks like mystance is making outbond connection with `192.168.200.21` however on port section it says cfinger .i.e. `192.168.201.22:cfinger`

what is cfinger here ?

```
commad PID    USER     FD   TYPE     Device    SIZE/OFF  NODE  NAME

java  13376  jmxtrans  28u   IPv4    58123807    0t0     TCP    myinstance:339976->192.168.201.22:cfinger (SYN_SENT)
java  13376  jmxtrans  29U   IPv4    58125689    0t0     TCP    myinstance:339977->192.168.201.22:cfinger (SYN_SENT)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run `lsof -P` it will return port number and not the service as defined in /etc/services.

So Java is running on whatever port cfinger is defined as in /etc/services. You could also just run `grep cfinger /etc/services` to find out what port it is as well.